# Laravel Cron Job Properly Work on a minute basis but not work for day basis

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-8

I write below code for executing some codes on a daily basis but it not work.

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
     $schedule->command('Delete:User')->daily();
}
```

When I try with minute basic the below code runs successfully

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->command('Delete:User')->everyMinute();
    }
```

Below image showing the setup in the server end
[image: Cronjob scheduled on server]

Please help me with this matter

Comment: you should have the scheduler run every minute

Comment: try running with `dailyAt();`

Comment: @bhucho tried with dailyAt(H:m); Still not working

Comment: @lagbox Can't I use once a day or something? Why should I use everyMinute only?

Comment: no, the scheduler itself needs to be ran every minute; `php artisan schedule:run` should be ran from cron every minute .... that is how it can catch all the possible times you have setup ... `daily` does not mean just once a day, it means at a specific time and if the scheduler doesn't run that minute it will miss it ... in the documentation it is setting up a cron job to run every minute to call the scheduler

Comment: @lagbox  Yeah, it's working.....   I used **dailyAt('Hour:minute');** and changed the cron interval to * * * * *

Comment: @lagbox Okay, I understood. Thank You very much.